# how to give width and height in power bi report in embedding

Tags: reactjs, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am working on a react project and I implemented a power BI embed to show report and I am having a issue with the size of generating report in the UI.
Here is the code for the Power BI Embed

```
 {selectedModel.AuthenticationMode !== null ? (
              <div className="iframe-container-powerbi">
                {generatedPowerBiToken && (
                  <PowerBIEmbed
                    embedConfig={{
                      type: "report",
                      id: generatedPowerBiToken.id,
                      embedUrl: generatedPowerBiToken.embedUrl,
                      accessToken: generatedPowerBiToken.accessToken,
                      tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
                      settings: {
                        layoutType: models.LayoutType.Custom,
                        customLayout: {
                          displayOption: models.DisplayOption.FitToPage,
                        },
                        panes: {
                          filters: {
                            expanded: true,
                            visible: true,
                          },
                        },
                        //background: models.BackgroundType.Transparent,
                      },
                    }}
                    eventHandlers={
                      new Map([
                        [
                          "loaded",
                          function () {
                            console.log("Report loaded");
                          },
                        ],
                        [
                          "rendered",
                          function () {
                            console.log("Report rendered");
                          },
                        ],
                        [
                          "error",
                          function (event) {
                            console.log(event.detail);
                          },
                        ],
                      ])
                    }
                    cssClassName={"report-style-class"}
                  />
                )}
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div className="iframe-container">
                <Iframe
                  url={ifActiveUrl}
                  width="100%"
                  height="100%"
                  id="modelIframe"
                  className="model-iframe"
                  display={ifUrlOpen ? "initial" : "none"}
                  position="relative"
                />
              </div>
            )}
```

and when I load a report UI is rendering like this

[image]

I need to increase the size of the chart and reduce the size of the space that noted with red color.
can anyone suggest a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue, set the height and width manually in the iframe instead of using 100%.Please find the reference code below:

```js
<iframe width="1080" height="520" src="Your_source_link" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

My output with height and width as 100%:
[image]

After changing the height and width:
[image]

Please find more references here:
[How to determine a Power BI report's width and height for embedding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44508590/how-to-determine-a-power-bi-reports-width-and-height-for-embedding)